# Django Passing Arguments from View to URL to View Again

Tags: python, django

So I have a Submit view and after something is submitted successfully, I want to do a `HttpResponseRedirect` to the `vote` view.

Here's my submit view:

```
def submit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SubmissionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            #Need to insert a link object into the database here
            url = reverse('vote', kwargs={'submit':True})
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        form = SubmissionForm
    return render_to_response('submit.html', {'form':form}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

And here's my vote view:

```
def vote(request, submit=False):
    return render_to_response('voting.html', {'submit':submit}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

My confusion is, what should I do in `urls.py` to pass the value of submit over to vote?

Currently, I have:

```
url(r'^$', 'vote', {'submit': True}, name='vote')
```

but I can't make it such that the value of the variable submit depends on what I passed from the submit view.

Does this make sense? I know its probably a very basic question. I'm new to Django and I'd really appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 url(r'^(?P<submit>.*)/$', 'vote', name='vote'),
```

Comment: And be sure to add the true value to the template call like so:

`{% url vote true.value %}`